# Why does xQueueReceive throw an unhandled exception (LoadProhibited)?

Tags: embedded, mqtt, esp32, uart, freertos

I'm working on an esp32 FreeRTOS application with two tasks. Its purpose is to take UART messages received from a peripheral device and transmit them via mqtt to a central broker.

The first task reads input from Serial1, processes the contents into a message structure, and adds it to a FreeRTOS queue:

```
typedef struct {
      int length;
      char buffer[AZ_EL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    } tag_message_t;
    
    void uart_read_task(void * pvParameters){
        BaseType_t xStatus;
        tag_message_t tag_message;
        while(true) {
            while(Serial1.available())
            {
                first_char = Serial1.read();
                if (first_char == '+')        // Indicates the beginning of a message
                {
                  for(int i = 0; i < AZ_EL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH; i++)
                  {
                    message_buffer[i] = Serial1.read();
    
                    if (message_buffer[i] == '\n') // End of message received
                    { 
                      ESP_LOGV(TAG, "Message found: %s", message_buffer);
                      strncpy(tag_message.buffer, message_buffer, i + 1);
                      tag_message.length = i + 1;
                      xStatus = xQueueSend(xMessagesToSendQueue, (void*) &tag_message, 0);
                      if (xStatus != pdPASS)
                        ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Failed to queue message.");
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
            vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(20)); // Wait the minimum BLE advertisement period for messages to come in, i.e. 20ms
        }
    }
```

The main loop() (which is technically the second FreeRTOS task) then attempts to receive from that queue and transmit over MQTT to a local broker:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Configure and start WiFi
  configure_network();
  connect_network();

  // Configure the MQTT connection
  configure_mqtt_client();

  // Configure and create the inter-task queues
  xMessagesToSendQueue = xQueueCreate(100, sizeof(tag_message_t));

  if (xMessagesToSendQueue == NULL) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unable to create messaging queue. Will not create UART handling message queue.");
    delay(10000);
    esp_restart();
  } else {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Messaging queue generated");
    configure_uart();
    xTaskCreate(uart_read_task, "UART_Processing", 20000, NULL, 1, NULL);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  const TickType_t xTicksToWait = pdMS_TO_TICKS(100); // milliseconds to wait
  tag_message_t received_message;

  if (network_connected) {
    connect_mqtt_client();
    while(mqtt_client.connected())
    {
      mqtt_client.loop();

      // Process messages on the xMessagesToSendQueue
      if (xMessagesToSendQueue != NULL)
      {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Processing message");
        if (xQueueReceive(xMessagesToSendQueue, &received_message, xTicksToWait) == pdPASS)
        {
          ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Received message, transmitting.");
          if(!mqtt_client.publish("aoa", received_message.buffer, received_message.length));
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Failed transmission.");
        }
        else
        {
          vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(50));
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Messages queue is null.");
      }
    }
  } else {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "WARNING Device not connected to the network. Reconnecting.");
    connect_network();
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

I've verified that the MQTT broker works, that it connects to WiFi, and it can properly read messages from Serial1. *HOWEVER*, the xQueueReceive() call in loop() throws a LoadProhibited exception every time it's called.

Can anyone tell me what I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: You're not null terminating `message_buffer` before you output it with `ESP_LOGV()` but that's probably not causing the problem. Where and how is `message_buffer` defined? It would help if you posted a minimal but complete program that demonstrates the problem. There are clearly things missing which might be relevant to memory corruption issues. Have you used the [ESP Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) to pinpoint where the exception is happening or are you guessing that it's `xQueueReceive()` in `loop()`?

Comment: Actually that might be the problem. If the message is `AZ_EL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH` bytes long then the way your code is written, `tag_message.buffer` won't be null terminated, and you're treating it as a C string so it really needs a `\0` at the end of it. You'll need to rework your code to leave room for the '\0' and make sure it's present.

Comment: adding - `strncpy(dst, src, n)` needs space for `n` to include room for the `\0` or it won't null terminate the copied string.

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone. I've implemented a means by which the strncopy adds a null termination (extended buffer length by 1 and assign \0). That didn't fix it but it turns out the issue had nothing to do with the copying. Turns out ESP32 doesn't play nicely with Serial1. I switched to Serial2 and everything works now. Will post an answer to close this out.

Answer (score 1):

All, thank you for your help. It turns out this wasn't a FreeRTOS issue. After a little research (i.e. reading this and watching a more experienced engineer explain things: [link]https://hackaday.com/2017/08/17/secret-serial-port-for-arduinoesp32/) it turns out ESP32 Serial1 pins are connected to flash memory.

Every time I tried Serial1.read() or Serial1.readBytesUntil() the ESP32 crashed. Turns out reading the flash is taboo?

I replaced '''Serial1.read()''' with '''Serial2.read()''' and others. That fixed everything. Now I'm off to optimizing my queues!

Comment: This begs the question as to why `Serial1` isn't working for you. That Hackaday article is an antique and misleading. `Serial1` should work without issue on the ESP32; you just need to specify the pins you're using to connect it. I often use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to receive an address on the Queue without casting it.

2 solutions: You either declare `received_message` as a Pointer:

```
tag_message_t* received_message;
...
received_message = new tag_message_t;
if (xQueueReceive(xMessagesToSendQueue, received_message, xTicksToWait) == pdPASS)
```

and don't forget to delete it right after usage.

Or you can cast it after receiving :

```
if (xQueueReceive(xMessagesToSendQueue, &received_message, xTicksToWait) == pdPASS)
        {
          received_message = *(static_cast<tag_message_t*>(&received_message));
          ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Received message, transmitting.");
          if(!mqtt_client.publish("aoa", received_message.buffer, received_message.length));
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Failed transmission.");
        }
```

or any other sort of dereferencing you might wanna try.

There is also the possibility `xQueueReceive` is already doing that! So let's be sure of what is going on by adding this:

```
ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Received message, transmitting. %s", received_message.buffer);
```

Right after you get the message.

I don't think `tag_message` is being deleted inside the task, so if the struct is still valid and present, if you properly parse/cast its address, you should be able to acquire the message without any issues.

Comment: I don't think you've identified the issue. The FreeRTOS queue is used correctly in the original post and type casting doesn't really change anything as the underlying variables behind pointers received by the queue API are already implicitly of the correct type. As long as the definition of `tag_message_t` is identical in both locations, there shouldn't be anything wrong.

Comment: @Tarmo is right about defining the queue correctly. I essentially copied the implementation of a Queue from the FreeRTOS documentation: [link]https://www.freertos.org/a00118.html. It turns out that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @nathan-almeida thank you for your response. I looked into it and xQueueReceive is copying everything from struct A to struct B, no static casting required. It turns out ESP32 Serial1 is connected to flash memory. So every time it tries to read Serial1 it crashes.